# Error in product page, Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product-page

I have an error in product page:

> "You cannot define a correlation name 'links' more than once"

Does anyone know what can it be? I tried to find answer for a long time.

This is a very basic site, no special modules or themes.

Thank you,
Eran

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with linked products, i.e. cross seller, up seller or something like that. The link collections joins the table with the alias `links` but usually only once. Did you customized something there? Does it occur for every product or only for some products?

Comment: Hello. No there is only 1 product in site. Could it be that the DB is broken?

Answer (score 1):

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-3-Inventory-stock-1-doesn-t-Exist-On-Magento-2-3/td-p/120679

By PankajS_Magento

Here is the command to run in DB SQL make sure to update dbname.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY 
INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS
select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id`   AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id`   AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id`     AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty`          AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku`                      AS `sku`
from (`dbname`.`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
   join `dbname`.`catalog_product_entity` `product`
        on ((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55475858/2539657